# How to render a new item to a collection with Backbone and CoffeeScript?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a small form to add an item, and a collection view that lists all items. However, I am not seeing, where/how to call render for a new item:

Form view:

```
class FastTodo.Views.AddTodoItem extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['todo_items/add_item']

  el: '#main'

  events:
    'submit': 'addItem'

  addItem: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.create task: $('#task').val()

  render: ->
    $(@el).html @template()

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new FastTodo.Collections.TodoItems()
    @render()
```

Collection View:

```
class FastTodo.Views.TodoItemsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['todo_items/index']

  render: ->
    console.log("render")

  renderOne: (item) ->
    console.log(item)

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new FastTodo.Collections.TodoItems()
    @collection.bind 'reset', =>
      @render()
    @collection.on 'add', (item) =>
      console.log('addd')
      @renderOne(item)
    @collection.fetch()
```

I would expect the output in the console to show a new item. However, I see:

[image: console output add new backbone view]

How do I render the new item on the collection? (or show that renderOne is triggered?)

Comment: Where are you creating the `AddTodoItem` view? You are not passing a collection to it when creating which causes the `undefined` error when you try to use it for creating a new todo.

Comment: that's my problem indeed, I want to create the views all on the router level. Any other option to have a collection bind to multiple views, without passing the collection from one view to the other?

Comment: you should have a global app variable which basically initializes everything, router, views, models etc. (like a main function in traditional languages) You could attach the collection to that global variable and let the views access it from there. Saying that it's not a good strategy. If your app wants to access a collection, it should be passed to it either directly or through parent view if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AddTodoItem` and your `TodoItemsIndex` need to share the exact same instance of the collection. This is the design of backbone. So your router should create a single instance of the collection and pass it in the options object to the constructors of both views. Then events will flow properly and the views will stay in sync. And to address your comment, don't pass the collection from one view to another, the wiring up of separate views should be handled via shared models/collections and code in the router level.

You can also have a global namespace for your application and a single shared collection there as is done [in the TodoMVC examples project here](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app.js), but I personally prefer independent modules to everything relying on shared globals.

Another approach to consider would be the [mediator pattern as described here](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#triggering-updates-in-other-views), although I think shared collections are much simpler and entirely sufficient in your case.